# How to use WKT in Google Maps V3?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, google-maps-api

We have a shape with the following WKT. The problem with Google Maps we normally extract out each of the lat and long value and put into an array and finally will do something like this. It works fine but in this WKT there are few sections in it but with OpenLayers I just put the whole WKT into this function `var feature1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(buffer.transform(P4326,P900913), null, styleObject);` it works perfectly fine without any issue.

How to resolve this for Google Maps?

```
polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                            paths: lineArray,
                                            strokeColor: '#1E90FF',
                                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                            strokeWeight: 2,
                                            fillColor: '#1E90FF',
                                            fillOpacity: 0.35
                                      });


POLYGON((100.54157334877087 5.124795579269911,100.50169157216737 5.175633231048347,100.48893060559693 5.190782519229377,100.48883685890004 5.190920674118928,100.48041685890006 5.206620683576352,100.48035625412166 5.206766524898229,100.48032538396345 5.206921338503033,100.48032543474828 5.207079174986367,100.48035640452454 5.207233968780704,100.48041710314108 5.207379771251712,100.48050519798412 5.207510979300314,100.48061730361823 5.20762255068534,100.48074911188677 5.20771019779251,100.4808955574719 5.207770552403195,100.4810510125519 5.2078012951316595,100.48120950307525 5.2078012445564505,100.48136493833998 5.2077704026211435,100.48151134505608 5.207709954559655,100.48164309689552 5.207622223348936,100.48175513070903 5.207510580439686,100.48184314109994 5.207379316194805,100.49022348868367 5.191753262740997,100.50293939440304 5.17665749276832,100.50295708150922 5.1766357380872146,100.55158138575345 5.114653464985341,100.61784836581363 5.047494669000269,100.63328064200411 5.045760273775513,100.63344538038619 5.045724117696659,100.63359900089658 5.045654696108101,100.63373481573457 5.045555031237853,100.63384691226155 5.045429461939012,100.64478691226155 5.030239472910412,100.64485714103375 5.030122067725934,100.64490643054278 5.029994524131959,100.64493336141338 5.029860514958455,100.64619300597558 5.018766440281411,100.89601933027687 4.76550530772389,100.90397540484798 4.76251382120199,100.904125498221 4.7624388147297605,100.90425680769607 4.762334529640712,100.90436366963635 4.762205463944471,100.91498366963637 4.746255474257608,100.9150580432529 4.746115668549328,100.91510356406134 4.74596407285823,100.91511847627667 4.745806534382425,100.91510220471923 4.745649129543159,100.9150553769999 4.7454979296113295,100.91497979931266 4.745358766531834,100.9148783867677 4.745237007978542,100.91475505095255 4.745137350316068,100.91461454905823 4.745063637454637,100.91446230038925 4.7450187125847965,100.9143041773355 4.745004308511336,100.91414627886799 4.745020980816285,100.91399469529519 4.74506808642927,100.91385527335358 4.745143808431712,100.91373339069273 4.745245226138226,100.89511556261954 4.764122863341007,100.89441924808347 4.764384677730915,100.92861460308248 4.729467265814491,100.94306861105032 4.717019660578351,100.94308862499464 4.717001837872207,100.9600648087706 4.70137140183913,100.97805150444233 4.690005163726286,101.0032978733881 4.688855369346559,101.02139744198907 4.698874409253193,101.02153571050398 4.698934873115156,101.02168284847642 4.698968658695525,101.02183372382656 4.698974587578459,101.02198307411716 4.698952452968966,101.02212569010408 4.698903026905675,101.0222565974315 4.698828033332999,101.02237123013421 4.698730087971819,101.02246558989572 4.698612607085813,101.03186692696475 4.684358662732975,101.04641937919912 4.681631913397546,101.04654522151539 4.6815976608810255,101.0466638985581 4.681543682997702,101.0626338985581 4.672663691919618,101.06265873346082 4.672649300079806,101.07193873346081 4.667049305582631,101.07206478644287 4.666955391993337,101.07217019642661 4.666838917858445,101.07225096922653 4.666704296595284,101.07230404420704 4.6665566292515965,101.07232741025584 4.66640151121859,101.07232018198869 4.666244820211681,101.07080124929709 4.655762184380661,101.06942217992568 4.64481956709879,101.06939272311594 4.6446829890795245,101.0693400432311 4.64455353405661,101.06926572348885 4.644435092618359,101.06457125429455 4.638224697426946,101.06319926512629 4.632065339533069,101.0631864279256 4.632015335107842,101.05965809799591 4.619901065378956,101.05729160630031 4.611301837098225,101.05827771116607 4.608078035110399,101.05837451798986 4.608017540493808,101.058489797227 4.607909126498835,101.05858164229866 4.607780378456879,101.0586465236503 4.607636244073435,101.05868194792791 4.607482262344451,101.05868655379639 4.607324350696963,101.05863655379638 4.60660435064062,101.05861127892128 4.606452707295678,101.05855757613483 4.606308606552095,101.05847739948697 4.606177291720301,101.0583736663157 4.606063540879937,101.05825015109548 4.605971493021525,101.05811134809807 4.605904497442384,101.05796230786196 4.605864991876384,101.05780845342177 4.60585441379272,101.05765538298354 4.605873148090809,101.05750866622635 4.605920513095127,101.05737364164183 4.60599478535917,101.05725522228572 4.606093262376247,101.05715771700969 4.6062123609150225,101.05708467367768 4.6063477474016885,101.05703875007214 4.60649449560441,101.05696615166936 4.606839338106436,101.05567666227104 4.611054977816131,101.05564623136308 4.611203092992834,101.05564409128449 4.611354267067325,101.05567031736118 4.611503179055542,101.05810031736118 4.6203331764030775,101.05810357207437 4.620344668666436,101.06162634972249 4.632439867617015,101.06303073487372 4.638744658859191,101.06308581972252 4.638907454598495,101.06317427651116 4.639054911411789,101.0678446649334 4.64523344260049,101.06919782007431 4.655970431325576,101.0691998180113 4.65598518148874,101.07064329274297 4.665947058557962,101.06183355569814 4.671263283392991,101.04599114859657 4.680072345516371,101.03123062080087 4.6828380888643055,101.03107509912326 4.682883713338254,101.030931837252 4.682959345378033,101.0308065956257 4.683061943874136,101.03070441010425 4.683187383417033,101.02152658363796 4.697102476341069,101.00388255801093 4.687335579811719,101.00374644848105 4.687275831277903,101.00360166061274 4.68724194258745,101.00345309409626 4.687235060553534,100.97776309409626 4.688405061901499,100.97762450889043 4.688423433455393,100.97749117130599 4.688465325320313,100.97736706846887 4.6885294848210455,100.95913706846886 4.700049496057161,100.95902137500535 4.700138148283603,100.9420012335367 4.715809084690873,100.9275313889497 4.728270349847366,100.92748140376511 4.728317234131123,100.89084289136436 4.765729386924607,100.88857903739637 4.7665805940663155,100.86875468604576 4.764747755821863,100.86852748525929 4.7647587762658,100.8479974852593 4.768688780791709,100.84779668516134 4.768755321284555,100.83633102855727 4.774306706231912,100.82703778821273 4.77294291672017,100.82687125841765 4.772935785811107,100.7928690382914 4.774982310566,100.7619067259743 4.772427068381073,100.76173502182992 4.772431140443018,100.7615680553451 4.772471265016521,100.76141336170892 4.772545631275547,100.76127792223743 4.772650883064091,100.7611678493072 4.772782270361311,100.6687278493072 4.910582361568241,100.66865301195101 4.91072185418806,100.66860697601827 4.910873227876582,100.6685915165044 4.911030646151936,100.66864137306756 4.972952505860876,100.66009346236922 4.9913004519727435,100.64595576422197 5.007756306956835,100.64586418982786 5.007887198342606,100.64580031240318 5.008033503784978,100.64576663858664 5.0081894820473565,100.64477291047628 5.016941706842589,100.61625125341138 5.0460532463404055,100.6130793579959 5.046409728012444,100.61291638011534 5.0464453024506675,100.61276420329115 5.046513443519312,100.61262930836556 5.0466112492457205,100.59598930836556 5.0615212630263375,100.59591729333239 5.061594575864115,100.58139729333239 5.078394589533011,100.5813745376085 5.078422128797729,100.568241718084 5.095052757503959,100.5558565329245 5.107692725364091,100.55190792815084 5.111630975719314,100.55184291849078 5.11170421172008,100.55150998857583 5.1121286259010175,100.50958140376511 5.154917596322795,100.50948245300847 5.155040676578281,100.50940948200127 5.155180602156629,100.50936528873167 5.155332007765464,100.50935156773907 5.155489087927182,100.50936884513898 5.155645819584137,100.50941645844956 5.155796193046173,100.509492581994 5.155934442424661,100.50959429690371 5.156055266717915,100.5097177030391 5.1561540330704085,100.50985806853575 5.156226954412539,100.51001001124239 5.156271234669731,100.51016770509305 5.1562851759732355,100.51032510350089 5.156268243762022,100.51047617120751 5.1562210872795635,100.51061511569779 5.156145514679759,100.51073660930729 5.156044423696323,100.54157334877087 5.124795579269911),(100.89871905240886 4.762767948943637,100.90896767267513 4.752376354194918,100.90316054789211 4.76109794021234,100.89871905240886 4.762767948943637),(100.64661349655054 5.015063009244003,100.64734548944385 5.008616000844607,100.66139423577802 4.992263705850945,100.66151334893807 4.99207906958164,100.67018334893807 4.973469079183367,100.67023954646196 4.9733033059172405,100.6702584834956 4.973129353908616,100.67020868057224 4.911274134430876,100.76224763699163 4.774072078648479,100.7927932740257 4.776592927682631,100.79290874158235 4.776594210842545,100.82688510588919 4.774549247104856,100.83634221178725 4.775937080726917,100.83650305821145 4.775944533666873,100.83666219668962 4.77592007401154,100.83681331483866 4.77586467197369,100.8484073218576 4.770251155446057,100.86871970000875 4.766362818665806,100.88843722762824 4.768185776370008,100.64661349655054 5.015063009244003),(100.89174944562149 4.767110780318271,100.89241584048753 4.766860216725576,100.83228546584598 4.827825906907718,100.89174944562149 4.767110780318271),(100.61964713897322 5.045671590739228,100.64435410761305 5.020630262940911,100.64335031023455 5.029471003274368,100.6327424559458 5.044199836724733,100.61964713897322 5.045671590739228),(100.57884271020993 5.084233488822919,100.58263439073833 5.079431891466035,100.59710904740169 5.062684368787789,100.61351808034122 5.047981338205527,100.61446663282223 5.047874732959801,100.57884271020993 5.084233488822919))
```

Control for 2 different polygon.

```
                if(pl==0)
                {
                      var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                    paths: cords,
                                                    strokeColor: '#1E90FF',
                                                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                                    strokeWeight: 2,
                                                    fillColor: '#1E90FF',
                                                    fillOpacity: 0.35
                                                  });
                    polygon1.setMap(map);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                    paths: cords,
                                                    strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                                                    strokeWeight: 2,
                                                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                                    fillOpacity: 0.25
                                                  });
                    polygon1.setMap(map);
                 }
```

Comment: Do you want to do the same thing in Google Maps API?

Comment: Yes I want the same thing in google map api else it look very funny shape. Any idea please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you need to make sure that your WKT string is properly formatted.

After that you can use a custom function to parse the string, and draw a polygon.
I could use the following code:

```
var wkt="POLYGON(...)"; //this is your WKT string

//using regex, we will get the indivudal Rings
var regex = /\(([^()]+)\)/g;
var Rings = [];
var results;
while( results = regex.exec(wkt) ) {
    Rings.push( results[1] );
}

var ptsArray=[];

var polyLen=Rings.length;

//now we need to draw the polygon for each of inner rings, but reversed
for(var i=0;i<polyLen;i++){
    AddPoints(Rings[i]);
}

var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: ptsArray,
    strokeColor: '#1E90FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#1E90FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  poly.setMap(map);


//function to add points from individual rings
function AddPoints(data){
    //first spilt the string into individual points
    var pointsData=data.split(",");


    //iterate over each points data and create a latlong
    //& add it to the cords array
    var len=pointsData.length;
    for (var i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
         var xy=pointsData[i].split(" ");

        var pt=new google.maps.LatLng(xy[1],xy[0]);
        ptsArray.push(pt);
    }


}
```

See a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/ajzX4/1/

Comment: Thank you codes works. I got one more thing to ask you here. I have updates and put this section of the codes. I what I want is that for the polygon with pl=0 to have the exact color and the rest I want to make it as transparent as possible what is best color combination to create it.

Comment: I could not understand what you want to do. Can you explain more?

Comment: sorry for my explanation. What I need is that for the first polygon I want the color to be #1E90FF but for the second and thereafter polygon the color to be transparent. The problem is that if I put the second polygon as white and lower the opacity value the first color #1E90FF resurface.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe almost gave up on this using my own WKT until I realized the regex doesn't account for spaces after the commas or after the initial shape name text.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - is this supposed to work for MULTIPOLYGON as well? Based on the altered fiddle I just tried, the google maps shapes that are rendered appear to drawn incorrectly.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/Ue9fC/2/)

Comment: @johntrepreneur: The code as I had posted, was only for Polygons, and not MultiPolygons. It should be easy to extend the code for Multipolygons. You will need to change the Regex, and the way you handle rings. I'm not sure if Gmaps supports Multipolygons. So that research needs to be done.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - thanks for confirming. Google Maps v3 does indirectly support additional separate polygons and also inner (polygon) rings, but not an actual MultiPolygon object. I did find [Wicket](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket) an open source lightweight library exactly for converting WKT to GMaps, but the author goes on to outline one of the [challenges he encountered when dealing with MultiPolygons](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket/issues/16). Is that something you encountered too?

Comment: Pretty late to the party, but I just found and solved a couple problems with this solution for complex, multi-hole polygons. First off, I discovered that WKT out of SQL Server Mgmt Studio is formatted with spaces after the commas between coord pairs. A call to js .replace() addresses that:
`var pointsData = data.replace(/, /g, ',').split(',');`
Secondly, WKT repeats the start point of rings at the end, and while Google Maps might not show that as an issue, it is an issue. The loop in the AddPoints() needs to be limited to `< pointsData.length - 1`

Comment: Finally, each ring needs to be in an array, path[] and the Google Maps constructor given an ARRAY of path[] elements. Not just a gigantic heap of all the rings points in the ptsArray as you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where I have found it first, when I needed it but this library is working perfect a fits all my needs when displaying WKTs on a google map:

```
var GeoJSON = function( geojson, options ){
    var _geometryToGoogleMaps = function( geojsonGeometry, opts, geojsonProperties ){
        var googleObj;
        switch ( geojsonGeometry.type ){
            case "Point":
                opts.position = new google.maps.LatLng(geojsonGeometry.coordinates[1], geojsonGeometry.coordinates[0]);
                googleObj = new google.maps.Marker(opts);
                if (geojsonProperties) {
                    googleObj.set("geojsonProperties", geojsonProperties);
                }
                break;

            case "MultiPoint":
                googleObj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < geojsonGeometry.coordinates.length; i++){
                    opts.position = new google.maps.LatLng(geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][1], geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][0]);
                    googleObj.push(new google.maps.Marker(opts));
                }
                if (geojsonProperties) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < googleObj.length; k++){
                        googleObj[k].set("geojsonProperties", geojsonProperties);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "LineString":
                var path = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < geojsonGeometry.coordinates.length; i++){
                    var coord = geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i];
                    var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(coord[1], coord[0]);
                    path.push(ll);
                }
                opts.path = path;
                googleObj = new google.maps.Polyline(opts);
                if (geojsonProperties) {
                    googleObj.set("geojsonProperties", geojsonProperties);
                }
                break;

            case "MultiLineString":
                googleObj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < geojsonGeometry.coordinates.length; i++){
                    var path = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i].length; j++){
                        var coord = geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][j];
                        var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(coord[1], coord[0]);
                        path.push(ll);
                    }
                    opts.path = path;
                    googleObj.push(new google.maps.Polyline(opts));
                }
                if (geojsonProperties) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < googleObj.length; k++){
                        googleObj[k].set("geojsonProperties", geojsonProperties);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "Polygon":
                var paths = [];
                var exteriorDirection;
                var interiorDirection;
                for (var i = 0; i < geojsonGeometry.coordinates.length; i++){
                    var path = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i].length; j++){
                        var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][j][1], geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][j][0]);
                        path.push(ll);
                    }
                    if(!i){
                        exteriorDirection = _ccw(path);
                        paths.push(path);
                    }else if(i == 1){
                        interiorDirection = _ccw(path);
                        if(exteriorDirection == interiorDirection){
                            paths.push(path.reverse());
                        }else{
                            paths.push(path);
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(exteriorDirection == interiorDirection){
                            paths.push(path.reverse());
                        }else{
                            paths.push(path);
                        }
                    }
                }
                opts.paths = paths;
                googleObj = new google.maps.Polygon(opts);
                if (geojsonProperties) {
                    googleObj.set("geojsonProperties", geojsonProperties);
                }
                break;

            case "MultiPolygon":
                googleObj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < geojsonGeometry.coordinates.length; i++){
                    var paths = [];
                    var exteriorDirection;
                    var interiorDirection;
                    for (var j = 0; j < geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i].length; j++){
                        var path = [];
                        for (var k = 0; k < geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][j].length; k++){
                            var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][j][k][1], geojsonGeometry.coordinates[i][j][k][0]);
                            path.push(ll);
                        }
                        if(!j){
                            exteriorDirection = _ccw(path);
                            paths.push(path);
                        }else if(j == 1){
                            interiorDirection = _ccw(path);
                            if(exteriorDirection == interiorDirection){
                                paths.push(path.reverse());
                            }else{
                                paths.push(path);
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(exteriorDirection == interiorDirection){
                                paths.push(path.reverse());
                            }else{
                                paths.push(path);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    opts.paths = paths;
                    googleObj.push(new google.maps.Polygon(opts));
                }
                if (geojsonProperties) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < googleObj.length; k++){
                        googleObj[k].set("geojsonProperties", geojsonProperties);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "GeometryCollection":
                googleObj = [];
                if (!geojsonGeometry.geometries){
                    googleObj = _error("Invalid GeoJSON object: GeometryCollection object missing \"geometries\" member.");
                }else{
                    for (var i = 0; i < geojsonGeometry.geometries.length; i++){
                        googleObj.push(_geometryToGoogleMaps(geojsonGeometry.geometries[i], opts, geojsonProperties || null));
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                googleObj = _error("Invalid GeoJSON object: Geometry object must be one of \"Point\", \"LineString\", \"Polygon\" or \"MultiPolygon\".");
        }

        return googleObj;

    };

    var _error = function( message ){
        return {
            type: "Error",
            message: message
        };
    };

    var _ccw = function( path ){
        var isCCW;
        var a = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < path.length-2; i++){
            a += ((path[i+1].lat() - path[i].lat()) * (path[i+2].lng() - path[i].lng()) - (path[i+2].lat() - path[i].lat()) * (path[i+1].lng() - path[i].lng()));
        }
        if(a > 0){
            isCCW = true;
        }
        else{
            isCCW = false;
        }
        return isCCW;
    };

    var obj;
    var opts = options || {};
    switch ( geojson.type ){
        case "FeatureCollection":
            if (!geojson.features){
                obj = _error("Invalid GeoJSON object: FeatureCollection object missing \"features\" member.");
            }else{
                obj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < geojson.features.length; i++){
                    obj.push(_geometryToGoogleMaps(geojson.features[i].geometry, opts, geojson.features[i].properties));
                }
            }
            break;

        case "GeometryCollection":
            if (!geojson.geometries){
                obj = _error("Invalid GeoJSON object: GeometryCollection object missing \"geometries\" member.");
            }else{
                obj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < geojson.geometries.length; i++){
                    obj.push(_geometryToGoogleMaps(geojson.geometries[i], opts));
                }
            }
            break;

        case "Feature":
            if (!( geojson.properties && geojson.geometry )){
                obj = _error("Invalid GeoJSON object: Feature object missing \"properties\" or \"geometry\" member.");
            }else{
                obj = _geometryToGoogleMaps(geojson.geometry, opts, geojson.properties);
            }
            break;

        case "Point": case "MultiPoint": case "LineString": case "MultiLineString": case "Polygon": case "MultiPolygon":
            obj = geojson.coordinates
                ? obj = _geometryToGoogleMaps(geojson, opts)
                : _error("Invalid GeoJSON object: Geometry object missing \"coordinates\" member.");
            break;

        default:
            obj = _error("Invalid GeoJSON object: GeoJSON object must be one of \"Point\", \"LineString\", \"Polygon\", \"MultiPolygon\", \"Feature\", \"FeatureCollection\" or \"GeometryCollection\".");
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: I will explore it but the Dev's script also is working but it just that I want to make all the polygon transparent except for the first one.

Comment: Convert all your WKTs using this tool, and collect all the polygons you get into an array. Then if you only want the first polygon to be transparent (to some extent), then use the setOptions command. For example: wktpolygons[0].setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.35});

Comment: no I want only the first polygon to be visible with the opacity of say 0.35 but the rest if possible not to have any color but just the shape is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Its possible. When you iterate through the polygons, for the first one use the fillColor: "#your_color_code", fillOpacity: 0.35 and for the rest don't use fillColor and fillOpacity but strokeColor: "#your_color_code" and maybe strokeOpacity

Comment: I tried your method with these settings var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: cords,strokeColor: '#1E90FF',strokeOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 2}); the color now it appear to have a blend of black n this #1E90FF. The reason being the first polygon is already set with this color and these other polygon are are within the bigger polygon.

Comment: If you dont want the unfilled polygons to blend with the first one set the zIndex attribute of the first polygon to 1 and all the other polygons' zIndex to 2 for example. That way the polygons coming after the first polygon will be displayed on top of the first one and since they will only have a stroke visible, then no blending should happen.

Comment: I tried like this  var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: cords,strokeColor: '#1E90FF',strokeOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 2,zIndex:2
              });  polygon1.setMap(map); its still the same effect no changes from the previous one.

Comment: any help on the indexing and positioning?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess but should that be multipolygon rather than polygon in your wkt?

How are you producing your wkt and what does google maps show at the minute?

Comment: I draw using the the google drawing tool first just a linestring then after I use jsts to draw a buffer size of certain size which generate this polygon. So what should I do next ?